# Is there any specefic pattern for keyboard lights flashing while system boots?

Tags: boot, keyboard, motherboard

Recently i noticed that all keyboard lights flashes when system is powered on ( prior to motherboard manufacturer screen.)

And when one of the HDD is selected the NUM lock light flashes.

When system reaches some init level all keyboard lights flashes again.(in linux it shows at init screen / in windows xp it is at windows logo )

And prior to shutdown , all keyboard lights flashes again.

Is this the general sequence ? Or is it manufacturer specefic ?
Can we detect any motherboard related problems if the lights doesn't flash at all ?

Comment: in genral keyboard lights will flash if keyboard was detected at startup and ram loading bootstrap of os

Comment: What is the brand of PC?

Comment: compaq presario (HP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the amount of different manufacturers of motherboards and keyboards I will say that no standard exists about keyboard lights. Remembering an old C/C++ axiom, you don't need any sort of input or output device (mouse/keyboard/display) to work in a computer.

This being said, there isn't any *explicit rule* that *all* keyboards need light.

I have a Microsoft keyboard and I can safely tell that the only light I know will always work is the `F Lock` key. Although on the pass of the bootloader to the actual OS the Numlock does flash a second, it is possibly a consequence of the Microsoft drivers acting on my keyboard.

I assume the most relevant problem one can find if the keyboard lights aren't working are the following:

- The PC's off (A: Turn it)
- The keyboard is not connected (A: Connect it)
- The USB / PS/2 port is busted (A: Fix it)
- Numlock, Capslock, etcetera, don't work
- And many others...

Most motherboards report their problems either in the POST or if it can't be done, by speaker beeps or LED flashes.